# How to get qps of a connection in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I know the `connection id` and want to get that QPS/TPS number.
I have tried:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Queries';

show global status;

show processlist;
```

---

I can get global(total) tps now, by

1. using `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Queries';` get value 30313827
2. wait 100s
3. run `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Queries';` again, get value 30362593
4. so it's about ~400 qps